# How do you get the community edition client of automation anywhere? and how do you get started with enterprise?

Tags: automation, rpa, automationanywhere

Automation Anywhere's client edition is no longer up for download in the latest version. I planned to use it for testing/learning purpose. When I signup it just emails me some credentials along with a URL to a cloud based client which works differently than the windows based client. Is there a way to get the community edition still?

Secondly, enterprise edition which I've downloaded asks me to login on first run or everytime I run it. Theres no way to use that for learning purposes, I suppose the credentials are created in a Web Control which I'll have to install on my own server. The Web Control is freely available to download as a 1.8 gb exe file, where does the payment/fee come in then? There's some 720 bucks per month mentioned on Automation Anywhere's website. PS Ive done the googling just that we don't have many tutorials on this except cloudfront and coursera MOOCs. Thank you!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should probably check out the latest A2019 community edition. The "client" is now web based, so you are building your bot in the browsers. running the bot is based on a bot agent. its a small download (a couple of 100MB)...

Community Edition: https://www.automationanywhere.com/products/enterprise/community-edition

Documentation for getting started: https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v2019/page/enterprise-cloud/topics/aae-client/bot-creator/using-the-workbench/cloud-work-area.html